# Why does the android Bitmap class not use the new keyword?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

As the title says, why does it not use the `new` keyword? Why do we have to create any new bitmaps in a static way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a design choice. The designers deemed it non-sensible to allow new Bitmap instances to be created *without* using one of the many (static) [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

One advantage is that it allows the factory methods to - if such is appropriate - return the *same* instance across multiple calls. Note that some Bitmaps returned are guaranteed to be [*immutable*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), and thus safely re-usable (which can avoid wasting memory with duplicated image data).

Use one of the [`Bitmap.createBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) factory method overloads to obtain a (possibly but not guaranteed to be new) Bitmap object.

Using `new Bitmap()` is not allowed because the Bitmap constructor is is [`private`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), such that only the factory methods can access it directly.